# Set default display value for dropdown using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display values 1,2,3,4,5 in a dropdown in VisualForce Page, however I want to display value '3' as selected by default.

```
<apex:page controller="sampleCon">
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, 'jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/jquery-1.8.3.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, 'jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js')}"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, 'jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css')}"/>

     <script type="text/javascript">
         var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

   j$('#noOfItems option').filter(function () {
   return j$(this).text() == '3';
})[0].selected = true;
        </script> 

 <apex:form >
    <br/>
        <apex:selectList size="1"  id="noOfItems" >
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}" id="test"/>

    </apex:selectList>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Here {!items} contains 1,2,3,4,5 and if i display 1 is getting selected as default.

I have tried many options from google but nothing is working for me. (jQuery is running fine)

Comment: try using val instead of text

Comment: Use `val()` function like `$('#noOfItems').val(3)`

Comment: Val() is not doing any change!

Comment: Is the script tag above the html in the document? If so, you either need to wait for the document to be ready or move the script below the html.

Comment: Thanks, Its a visualforce page. so i can not include html. I have added j$( "document ).ready(function() {" still not working